# Best way to store form values in PHP Cookie?

Tags: php, cookies

After a form submission I would like to store several specified form values in a PHP cookie.  I need the data to persist after the browser is closed so I don't want to use sessions.  My current call looks like this:

```
if ($_GET) {
    $params = $_GET;
}
```

Is there a way to set several params from $_GET to a $_COOKIE so I can use them later when the user returns?

Comment: RTFM (http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Comment: sorry...should have done that first I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use **sessions** for you problem. Just change the cookie parameters with `session_set_cookie_params()` (see [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)) to a time > 0 (0 implies that it should be deleted when the browser is closed) and increase the session cache lifetime with `session_cache_expire()` (see [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-expire.php)).

This has the advantage that even data that the client shouldn't be able to change cannot be changed by simply changing the cookie on his machine.

**Cookies only**

The other approach could include some serialization (e.g. use `serialize()` and `deserialize()` or do something on your own for things of low complexity like simply joining some arguments with a delimiter) of your parameters directly stored into a cookie with the `setcookie()` function. Get more info about that [here](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php). With that you can read out the cookies values directly from the superglobal `$_COOKIE`.

Comment: That's something I never new...I'll look into this as it may solve another issue :)  Thanks!

Comment: @Paul nothing actually new in using a tool in a perverted way. Someone used a state seal to crack nuts while ago. Session is alive until browser is closed. You are right while this guy is wrong.

Comment: @YourCommonSense this is just not true. In common language a session cookie does describe one that is deleted after the current session (so as soon as the browser is closed). But in php it is possible to use the same mechanism of sessions to store data over longer time by changing the cookie parameters and the caching time. A valid point against it would be, that the data may be stored in a inefficient and uncontrollable way whereas a database would be more reliable. However it has the very big benefit of providing data protection and usage simplicity in contrast to a direct cookie approach.

Comment: Like many newbie programmers you are confusing sessions and cookies purpose. With more experience you'll learn to distinguish them.

Comment: And of course, we are talking of the "data protection" in case of query string supplied data. Stackoverflow theoretics are so theoretics.

Answer (score 0):

Check the PHP documentation for setcookie: http://php.net/setcookie

Answer (score 0):

You can use serialize(), or do a foreach() loop of all $_GET values, and set those in the cookies (different cookie for each value)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `foreach` to traverse through GET array and set the cookies with their index names.
try this -

```
$expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
foreach($_GET as $k=>$v){
   setcookie($k,$v,$expire);
}
```

This will set cookie names same as GET array indexes and will be expired after a month.